# can't restore a database from a 100.50 backup on a 100.0 server

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, versions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to restore Sql Server 2008 backup in sql server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545316/is-it-possible-to-restore-sql-server-2008-backup-in-sql-server-2005)

I have a backup that was made on MS SQL Server 100.50 version, and I attempt to restore it on a  MS SQL Server 100.0 version. I get an error message "*The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.1617. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 10.00.5500. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server.*". So how do I restore it? I can see following solutions:

1. Create a backup for my version of database. To do this I've tried to set the compatibility level of the original database on 100.50 server to 90 (MS SQL Server 2005), but it still produces same backup file. Haven't found other ways to do it.
2. Update my SQL Server instance to 100.50 version. Haven't found how to do it yet.

Maybe there are other ways to solve this problem about which I am not aware yet. Any advice is welcome!

Comment: While the given duplicate is for different versions, the answer is the same, it cannot be done with backup/restore. If you want more help with actual migration or copying, you should ask on [dba.se] instead of here.

Answer (score 0):

Install another instance of the database version you have the backup from.
Then you can restore you backup into this instance.
After that you can use the migrations tool to move the content of the database back to you old server.

That is how I did it when I had the same problem once.
Maybe someone else post a more tricky way.

Comment: What is the migration tool? Where can I find it?

Comment: Sorry, more specify -> Rights mouseclick the database, all tasks (import/export data). This is a wizard that help you create some Packages to move your data from one database to another. If you have to make conversions you can safe such a packet and modify it with BI version of Visual Studio.