# How to restore SQL Server 2014 backup in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

Were there any changes in this area with SQL Server 2014? I’ve seen this post [Is it possible to restore Sql Server 2008 backup in sql server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545316/is-it-possible-to-restore-sql-server-2008-backup-in-sql-server-2005) and I know that this was not possible as a scenario for 2012 -> 2008 but I wonder if MS made any changes here with the 2014 version.

We are evaluating 2014 version and we have a fairly large database in testing. We’d like to restore a backup of that database to SQL Server 2008 because that physical machine has more space, RAM,…

I’m getting standard error message when I try to restore backup but I was wondering if there is something else in SQL Server 2014 that I might be missing.

Comment: It's never possible to go backwards with the backups like this - see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545316/

Comment: So, when they were writing the code for the 2008 product, they had to already be aware (perfectly) of the changes in the database structure that would be happening in half a decade's time and write code to deal with such a structure?

Comment: if you haven't used sql server 2012 or sql server 2014 feature then what you can try is take properties of database from management studio.click options then change compatibility level to Sql server 2008 (100). then take backup of your database and try restoring it

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/468578/move-database-from-sql-server-2012-to-2008

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not really as far as I know but here are couple things you can try.

Third party tools: Create empty database on 2008 instance and use third party tools such as [ApexSQL Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx) and [Data Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_datadiff.aspx) to synchronize schema and tables.

Just use these (or any other on the market such as Red Gate, Idera, Dev Art, there are many similar) in trial mode to get the job done.

Generate scripts: Go to Tasks -> Generate Scripts, select option to script the data too and execute it on 2008 instance. Works just fine but note that script order is something you must be careful about. By default scripts are not ordered to take dependencies into account.

Comment: This tools doeasn't support sql server 2014 :(

Comment: You can use Generate Scripts from Sql Server 2014.  Be sure and carefully review/edit the script.  I just did this, and had to edit the path where the data and log files are created, and remove creation of users (which I could have suppressed as an option while generating the script).

Comment: An open source option for synchronizing databases is [OpenDBDiff](https://github.com/OpenDBDiff/OpenDBDiff).

Answer (score 38):

No, it is not possible.  Stack Overflow wants me to answer with a longer answer, so I will say  no again.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql#compatibility

> Backups that are created by more recent version of SQL Server cannot
>   be restored in earlier versions of SQL Server.

Comment: it would be better if you share some link to MS documentation

Comment: Software companies rarely offer documentation on features that aren't offered by the products they produce.

Comment: "Stack Overflow wants me to answer with a longer answer, so I will say no again." ;)

Comment: @DaveMarkle but sometimes they do ;).

Answer (score 3):

It is a pretty old post, but I just had to do it today. I just right-clicked database from SQL2014 and selected Export Data option and that helped me to move data to SQL2012.

Comment: This only copies data from views and tables; it's fine if that's all you want, but it isn't the same as restoring a database with schema, stored procs, etc.

Comment: Use Tasks > Generate Scripts to export a database with schema, stored procs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old question... but I had the same problem today and solved with script, a little bit slow and complex but worked. I did this:

Let's start from the source DB (SQL 2014) right click on the database you would like to backup -> **Generate Scripts** -> "Script entire database and all database objet" (or u can select only some table if u want) -> the most important step is in the "**Set Scripting Options**" tab, here you have to click on "**Advanced**" and look for the option "**Script for Server version**" and in my case I could select everything from SQL 2005, also pay attention to the option "**Types of data to script**" I advice "**Schema and data**" and also Script Triggers and Script Full-text Indexes (if you need, it's false by default) and finally click ok and next. Should look like this:

[image: Set Scripting Options]

Now transfer your generated script into your SQL 2008, open it and **last Important Step**:
You must change **mdf** and **ldf** location!!

That's all folks, happy F5!! :D

Comment: it's not working either. at one script it fails :(

Comment: @Moeez what kind of error it gives you? Also you changed the mdf and ldf location according to the new server file path?

Answer (score 0):

No I guess you cannot restore the databases from higher version to lower version , you can make data flow b/w them i,e you can scriptout.
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/

Answer (score 0):

Please use SQL Server Data Tools from SQL Server Integration Services (Transfer Database Task) as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27777823/2127493

Answer (score 0):

If you have both versions you can create a merge replication from new to old. Create a merge publication on your newer sql server and a subscription on the older version. After initializing the subscription you can create a backup of the database with the same structure and the same content but in an older version and restore it on your old target server.
You can use this method also with sql server 2016 to target 2014, 2012 or 2008.