# Migrate SQL Server database 2012 to 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have database that runs on SQL Server 2012. Now I need to move this database to new PC and run it on SQL Server 2014.

What is the best way to do it? I far as I understood it is not possible to backup in 2012 and restore to SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can restore a SQL Server 2012 backup into a SQL Server 2014 instance. [See here](http://forums.asp.net/post/5785670.aspx).

Please note, you cannot go the other way - you cannot restore a SQL Server 2014 backup into a SQL Server 2012 instance. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042746/possible-to-restore-a-backup-of-sql-server-2014-on-sql-server-2012).