# Restore big database from SQL server 2014 into SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I just bought a new 2008 SQL server license and am now trying to move my 10gb database from 2014 express(12.0.5203) to 2008 (10.0.1600.22)

I have tried the "export DB to script" way, but the file is very big(20GB) and a lot of data is not getting imported because of several datatype convertion errors.

Currently I am trying to copy the data by scripts like

```
  SELECT    *
  INTO  database.dbo.table
  FROM OPENQUERY([localhost\WAWI], '    SELECT *
  FROM [localhost\WAWI].database.dbo.[table]')
```

While having created a connection in sys.servers

```
  EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='WAWI'

  EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'localhost\WAWI', 'false', NULL, 'sa', 'password'
```

But while executing the import script I am not able to connect to the local 2014 server even so I have opened it in the object explorer in a query window opened by the remote 2008 server

I get the following error message

> The OLE DB provider 'SQLNCLI10' for linked server 'WAWI' has the message 'Login timeout expired' return.
>   The OLE DB provider 'SQLNCLI10' for linked server 'WAWI' has the message ' network-related or instance-specific error when establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server could not be found, or it can not be accessed. Verify that the instance name is correct and that allows SQL Server remote connections. For more information in SQL Server Books Online.' return.
>   Message 53, level 16, State 1, line 20
>   Named pipes provider: it could be made cannot connect to SQL Server [53].

Comment: How did you just buy license for Sql Server 2008? It is a horrible idea to go from an newer version down to an older version (the predicament you are in now). You MIGHT be able to downgrade/restore to 2012 and then down to 2010 and then down to 2008.

Comment: I got a good deal on ebay because I needed to step up performance in case of core usage as well as the place which is getting small since express only has around 10 GB per DB... in short no money <<

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore SQL Server 2014 backup in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743956/how-to-restore-sql-server-2014-backup-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: How many tables?? If you aren't using any features added since 2008 (fingers crossed) then you might be able to script out the schema and then muddle with trying to import your data (IDENTITY INSERT OFF will be friendly at this point)

Comment: about 150 tables and I think no newer features are beeing used

Comment: That answer in the duplicate link above mentions third party tools that may be of assistance. Good luck.

Comment: Used the following programm in trial version, worked like a charm http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_datadiff.aspx

Comment: You are lucky. I am glad it worked.