# Error while Restoring backup in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2014, database-backups

'Restore Failed' error is getting displayed when trying to restore the backup.

After searching here, it came to my knowledge that higher version of SQL Server (2014) database backups cannot be restored in earlier/lower/older(SQL Server 2005) version.

My query is that can I set the compatibility mode to that of 2005 and than take backup, will that work?

If not, are there any other possible tool or solutions because the backup is pretty big and takes 2-3 hours for back-up to get complete.

Comment: The only option you have is to restore on 2014 server or higher

Comment: Actually it was intended for that purpose only, but one client has a professional version of SQL Server 2005 and is not ready to upgrade it.

Comment: The backup from higher version will never be restored on lower. You can script the entire database and use bcp to export/import data. But it will take much more time. And this will be work only if you don't use any feature not supported by 2005

Comment: Thanks @sepupic for your quick replies, I guess I'll have to manually verify & alter many procedures to make it compatible with 2005 version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQL 2014 database backup cannot be restored to a SQL 2005 database.
What you can do, is;

```
 1. script out all objects from the SQL 2014 database;
   1.1 right click database in Object Explorer
   1.2 select 'Tasks' -> 'Generate Scripts'.
   1.3 Enable everything, including 'script data'.
 2. Create a new database on SQL 2005
 3. Run all scripts on the new SQL 2005 database.
```

However, as your database is pretty big, this will take a long time.
Especially scripting the data.

If you really need to do this, you could script out all tables, procedures etc., and create a data flow using e.g.SSIS to migrate the data into SQL 2005.

**Edit**;
another option I found ([on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743956/how-to-restore-sql-server-2014-backup-in-sql-server-2008?rq=1)), but have not tested, is using third party tools,
'Create empty database on 2008 instance and use third party tools such as ApexSQL Diff and Data Diff to synchronize schema and tables.

Just use these (or any other on the market such as Red Gate, Idera, Dev Art, there are many similar) in trial mode to get the job done.'

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion seems helpful although I think I might face some issue regarding SP's which won't permit functionality of SQL 2008 and higher versions